# Move Chevron in Fluent UI Nav to Right Side

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluentui-react

In any of the Nav examples at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/nav how would I go about moving the Chevron from the left side to the right side?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple with `styles` property of `Nav Component`:

```
<Nav
  ...
  styles={{
    chevronButton: {
      right: 0,
      left: 'none',
    }
  }}
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/OJgaozo?editors=0010) working example.